# Two Factor Authentication Client for Windows 10

Tags: gratis, security, password-manager, windows-10, two-factor-authentication

I'm looking for a [Two Factor Authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-factor_authentication) Client like [Google Authenticator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.authenticator2&hl=en) but for Windows. My requirements are,

- Gratis
- Be able to store multiple entries with labels
- Easy to use
- Runs on Windows 10

I would also like the software to have these features but they are not a necessary,

- Password protect interface on launch
- Encrypted database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The one I currently use now is called WinAuth. It meets all my requirements including the ability to password protect the interface and encrypt the database. It also supports YubiKeys which is an added bonus.

## [WinAuth](https://winauth.com/)

> #### Portable open-source Authenticator for Windows
>
> WinAuth is a portable, open-source Authenticator for Windows that can
> be used as a 2FA including Bitcoin / crypto-currency websites, any
> service that requires the Google Authenticator, and games such as
> World of Warcraft, Diablo III, Guild Wars 2, Rift, ArcheAge. WildStar,
> Runescape and Steam.
>
> The project is open-source and hosted at
> https://github.com/winauth/winauth.
>
> [image: WinAuth UI]

Answer (score 0):

I also know of Authy which also meets all my requirements. It has a cool Phishing Detection feature which WinAuth does not. It's available for most popular devices as well. Authy is available as a Chrome extension.

## [Authy App for Desktop](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/authy/gaedmjdfmmahhbjefcbgaolhhanlaolb?hl=en)

> Authy is a simple way to manage Two-Factor Authentication accounts.
>   Authy supports GMail, Dropbox, Lastpass and thousands of other sites.
>
> [image: Authy]

Comment: Unfortunately, Authy for desktop isn't offered anymore. There is an addon available for Google Chrome though.

Comment: @StevenVascellaro Thanks for pointing that out, I've updated the answer accordingly.