# Is there an offline two factor authentication client for Linux that I can use as TFA with Gmail, Dropbox, etc.?

Tags: linux, security, two-factor-authentication

In short, I have an offline desktop at home that I would like to use as a "dongle" for certain services. This desktop runs Debian Linux and does not have Chrome or Chromium. (It's offline! So I figure why bother?)

I've seen [this question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/25075/14591), but obviously WinAuth and Authy are Windows and/or Chrome only. Basically I'm looking for something like FreeOTP or Google Authenticator but that runs on Linux. Ideally it would be open-source, lightweight, and able to run in a terminal.

I am *not* trying to enable two factor authentication on the desktop; I'm trying to use it as the "physical thing I have" part of the TFA process.

EDIT: Also, I know that I can run

```
import pyotp
totp = pyotp.TOTP("BASE32SECRET3232")
totp.now()
```

in Python to get the timed code, but I'm trying to avoid rolling my own OTP program if I can help it (since I'm sure there are nuances that I would miss)